# Rearrange formula in term of r

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I do not know how to arrange following equation in term of r:
$$I = P\left(1 + {r \over 100}\right)^n $$

I know that first step is dividing both parts of equation by P:

$$ {I \over P} = \left(1 + {r \over 100}\right)^n$$

But here I got stuck. I do not know how to extract r out of the power. Square root does not help because it is square root of whole $1 + {r \over 100}^ n$

Comment: $$\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{I}{P}} = 1+\dfrac{r}{100};$$  $$etc.$$

Comment: I re-tagged this as `algebra-precalculus` (`linear-algebra` is a whole other animal) and made a minor-minor adjustment to your formatting (bigger parentheses). I didn't touch your final expression, $1 + \frac{r}{100}^n$, which is "incorrect" (in that it doesn't match what you had already typed twice), because I wasn't sure if it speaks to your road block involving the square root (or the $n$th root, as the case may be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you're on the right track so far. I believe that next you would take the $n$th root of both sides. Afterward, multiply everything by $100$, and finally subtract $100$ from the right hand side.